# onClick of SVG Map background color should be active only for parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using SVG Map for India, it is working fine, but the issue is
parent ID is not deactivating if I am clicking any other state, I need
parent Id should deactive with "fill color - Grey" and child color
should be active in Green.

attached image for reference, pleas take a look.

[SVG India Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiiXE.png)

I am using below Jquery code for background:

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('path[id^="map_"]').click(function(){
      $(this).css('fill', "green");
    });
  });
 </script>
```

http://www.acmearchitectural.com/indiamapsvgfiles/map.html#

Answer (score 0):

I would first deactivate all the states, then use `fill` on the target:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('path[id^="map_"]').click(function(){
            var t = $(this)
                th;

            $('path[id^="map_"]').each(function () {
                th = $(this);
                if (th.attr("id") !== t.attr("id")) {
                    th.css('fill', 'gray');
                } else {
                    t.css('fill', "green");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Its not working at all I tried it... instead of "parentID" i tried "map_" its selecting all state on cliking. here is JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/1fvbzc2q/

Comment: I ran this on your fiddle and it seems to do what you are looking for - please check it when you have a chance